# Query params not working properly

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In my Angular2 app I need to pass some **optional** arguments to a route.
Because they are optional, I decided to use `queryParams`.

I am using the following code to pass the argument:

```
public recoverPassword() {
    this.router.navigate(
        ['/access/recover-password', 
        { queryParams: { 'email': this.model.email }} ]
    );
}
```

I get this URL:

```
http://localhost:4200/access/recover-password;queryParams=%5Bobject%20Object%5D
```

As you can see, the parameter is completely wrong. And I can't parse it the in target component. The correct url should be:

```
http://localhost:4200/access/recover-password;email=myemail@gg.com
```

I followed the [official doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#optional-route-parameters), but I can't find a working solution.

Comment: Please spell-check your post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`queryParams` should be passed as a second argument (to be more precise, it is just a part of optional second argument `NavigationExtras`, you can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html)), not as a part of first argument which is a route you want to navigate to. This should do the trick:

```
public recoverPassword() {
    this.router.navigate(
        ['/access/recover-password'], 
        { queryParams: { 'email': this.model.email } }
    );
}
```